Kronecker Decomposition Algorithm
I am looking for an algorithm that decomposes a $2^n$ square matrix into a Kronecker product $\otimes$ of $n$ number of  $2 \times 2$ matrices.
Does anyone know if there is an implementation out there (in python) or, there are general strategies to build such an algorithm?
Approximate decomposition is fine for me too.

please see this article: https://doi.org/10.1155/2023/9111626
